# how to configure the grub.cfg file on redhat 7 in order to boot from specific kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, grub, rhel7, operating-system

In Red Hat EL versions 5 and 6 we can easily to update the `/etc/grub.conf` in case we want to change the kernel by default variable

```
 For example , grub.conf on redhat 5
 default=0
 timeout=5
 #splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
 #hiddenmenu
  title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.18-410.el5)
   root (hd0,0)
   kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-410.el5 ro root=/dev/rootvg/slash
   initrd /initrd-2.6.18-410.el5.img
  title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.18-409.el5)
    root (hd0,0)
   kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-409.el5 ro root=/dev/rootvg/slash
   initrd /initrd-2.6.18-409.el5.img
```

From this `/etc/grub.conf` if we want to boot from kernel  `2.6.18-409` version
then we just change the `default=1`.
So on the next boot, the OS will start with the old kernel

RHEL7 is very different.  I find in the RHEL7 the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
But I don't understand how to change the file in order to boot from other kernel as I do it on RHEL5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How the change GRUB kernel on redhat 7 version**

To list all the menu entries that will be displayed at system boot, issue the following command:

```
 # awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
 0 : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64) 7.2 (Maipo)
 1 : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64) 7.2 (Maipo)
 2 : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, with Linux 0-rescue- b2c5e6a1c5ea4cb5be82100bd7dc3469
```

How to verify what is the current entry (the current kernel from /etc/default/grub )

```
# grub2-editenv list
  saved_entry=1
```

This mean the current kernel version from grub configuration is: **3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64**

let’s check what is the current kernel version on the machine:

```
# uname -r
  3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

Now let’s changes the kernel version from GRUB configuration so Linux will boot with the higher kernel - 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 ,

remember from the awk command we get entrie number 0

So the setting should be as the following

```
 # grub2-set-default 0
```

Now we check the new GRUB configuration by

```
 # grub2-editenv list
   saved_entry=0
```

so now the new GRUB configuration
is set to kernel version: **3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64**

Now we reboot the machine

```
 # Reboot
```

After reboot Linux was up with the new kernel

```
 # uname -r
   3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: May be you need to enter one more command after `grub2-set-default 0`
where 0 is the no. of the desired kernel. And then
`grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: I wanted to change default boot loader to be windows which is the third one.  I issued grub2-set-default 2.   This worked!

Answer (score 3):

change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` to the number that you want, now you need to regenarate the grub2 config using `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: just one remark - I not find the GRUB_DEFAULT in the file grub.cfg , cat /boot/grub2/grub.cfg|grep GRUB_DEFAULT , this variable exist in other file?

Comment: @dandan was my foul, I edited my answer with the filename that you need to edit

Comment: I think the seting of the default shuld be by the command - grub2-set-default N , while N is the entrie from awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg

Comment: @dandan don't edit that file by hand.

Comment: please see my post , what you think about ?

Comment: @dandan is another way to change the default kernel, better then edit the file manually..